# Laravel Sum by Value

Tags: php, sql, laravel

This is my table :

[image]

If I use this :

```
{{$periode->pakan->sum('jumlah_masuk')}}
```

The result is **"55"**

What if I want `sum('jumlah_masuk')` but only `value='s10'` from `('Jenis_pakan')`?

Comment: please provide a expected result for more clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the below query,

```
{{$periode->pakan->where('Jenis_pakan', 's10')->sum('jumlah_masuk')}}
```